# Generating multivariate normal random variables only using unif

Tags: r, random-generation

How can I generate n multivariate normal random variables only using the runif function (with mu and sigma). I know how to use box muller transformation, but not sure where to go from there once generated the random normal.

Comment: First you need indep normal RVs. Then peraps [this Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1598940/managing-a-bond-fund-simulating-the-maximum-of-correlated-normal-variates/1598959#1598959). And links.

Answer (score 2):

If the vector to generate is $\mathbf X=(X_1,\ldots,X_p)\sim\mathcal N_p(\mu,\Sigma)$, then one can generate $X_1$, $X_2|X_1$, $X_3|X_1,X_2$, which are all univariate Normals 
\begin{align}
X_1 &\sim \mathcal N(\mu_1,\Sigma_{11})\\
X_2|X_1=x_1&\sim \mathcal N(\mu_2+\frac{\Sigma_{12}}{\Sigma_{11}}(x_1-\mu_1),\Sigma_{22}-\Sigma_{12}^2/\Sigma_{11}^2)\\
X_3|X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2&\sim \mathcal N(\mu_3+\frac{\Sigma_{13}}{\Sigma_{11}}(x_1-\mu_1)+\frac{\Sigma_{23}}{\Sigma_{22}}(x_2-\mu_2),\\
&\qquad\Sigma_{33}-(\Sigma_{13},\Sigma_{23})\Sigma_{1:2}^{-1}(\Sigma_{13},\Sigma_{23})^\text{T})\\
&\vdots\end{align}
and can rely on a Box-Muller step each.

An alternative is to generate $p$ iid $\epsilon_i\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$ by Box-Muller. And apply the location scale transform
$$\mu+\Sigma^{1/2} (\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_p)^\text{T}$$

Comment: +1 When "$\Sigma^{1/2}$" is computed with a suitable algorithm (*e.g.*, Cholesky decomposition), I understand the results will be more accurate than the sequential (Gram-Schmidt) method illustrated at the outset.  But the sequential method is interesting in its own right.

Comment: @whuber: actually both approaches are exact in the formal sense they both produce a random vector with the right distribution. The vectorial approach may however be more efficient since it avoids all the inversions in the sequential method.

Comment: I was referring to floating point computation rather than mathematical correctness.  There also may be an issue with non-invertibility of the $\Sigma_{1:2}$ *etc.*